# Delete field_group programmatically

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a field_group called "group_imagecache" in Drupal 7. How would I delete this programmatically?

I have tried reading the code and it seems it uses ctools, but I would rather not use ctools.

Answer (score 9):

ctools is a dependency of field_group. If you want to interact with field groups programmatically, you'll need to do so through ctools' API.

Fortunately, it isn't hard in this case. Something like the following should work:

```
if ($group = field_group_load_field_group($group_name, $entity_type, $bundle_name, $mode)) {
  ctools_include('export');
  field_group_group_export_delete($group, FALSE);
}
```

Just grep for those functions in the field_group module for more information.

Comment: If you are not sure what the `$mode` variable should be take a look in the `field_group` table. For me it was `form`.

Comment: `$mode` is either `form` if it's a group on the node form or it's the name of the view mode (normally `default`) if it's a group on the display.

Comment: It just includes the correct file from the ctools module so that the export functionality is available: http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21ctools%21ctools.module/function/ctools_include/7.